# how to speed up PHPExcel reader

Tags: php, phpexcel, phpexcelreader

HI all expert i am newbie in php.
can anyone tell me to speed up PHPExcel and this is my code ,it read 20000 rows with 4 columns . it take more than 15s. thank you so much

```
function upload_fl($FILES){

$file = $FILES['excel'];

//echo getcwd();
//print_r($file);

require 'phpexcel/PHPExcel.php';

if(move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'],'C:/wamp/www/datatable_017/php/upload/'.$file['name'])){

    $data = '../php/upload/'.$file['name'];

    $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($data);
    $sheetData = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null,true,true,true);

    //var_dump($sheetData);

    echo sizeof($sheetData);
    //$writefile = fopen($FILES['excel']['name'].'.txt','w');
    /*
    foreach($sheetData as $row){
        foreach($row as $col->$value){
            //$value_inser = (is_numeric($value) == true ? ''number',''.$value.'',''':''text','',''.$value.''');
            //fwrite($writefile,$cate_set_id[$col].','.$com_id.','.$year.','.$value_insert.'\n');
        }
    }
    -->
    fclose($writefile);
    */
    return 'upload/'.$file['name'].'.txt';
}else{
    return 'upload failed';
}
}//function
```

Comment: A csv would be faster

Comment: I had to manipulate big xls in the past. Instead of using PHPExcel, I converted the xls into csv, and then read it using classic php functions. Hope that helps

Comment: but , csv doesn't support my language...

Comment: Csv is language agnostic

Comment: Some versions of Excel have trouble displaying non-ascii characters, which can be a problem for non-English languages.

Comment: What does `$FILES['excel'];` contain? CSV data? XLS? XLSX?

Comment: it is XLSX . it is upload file . i upload and then i data from it to insert mysql by using load data infile. $FILES['excel']['name']....

Comment: Adrien - most versions of Excel files have no problem displaying non-ascii characters; just configure it to the appropriate language settings or use UTF-8..... but that has nothing to do with the question

Comment: If you want to work with large Excel files, first suggestion is not to build a large PHP array in memory by making that `toArray()` call, because that's a big overhead in memory usage, and there's also a big cost in performance with the constant need to allocate more and more memory as the array is built..... if you're going to process a row at a time, use the iterators built into PHPExcel, or just use a loop over the individual rows

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple worksheets, but don't need to load all of them, then you can limit the worksheets that the Reader will load using the setLoadSheetsOnly() method. To load a single named worksheet:

```
$inputFileType = 'Excel5'; 
$inputFileName = './sampleData/example1.xls';
$sheetname = 'Data Sheet #2'; 
/**  Create a new Reader of the type defined in $inputFileType  **/
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
/**  Advise the Reader of which WorkSheets we want to load  **/ 
$objReader->setLoadSheetsOnly($sheetname); 
/**  Load $inputFileName to a PHPExcel Object  **/
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
```

Or you can specify several worksheets with one call to setLoadSheetsOnly() by passing an array of names:

```
$inputFileType = 'Excel5'; 
$inputFileName = './sampleData/example1.xls';
$sheetnames = array('Data Sheet #1','Data Sheet #3'); 
/** Create a new Reader of the type defined in $inputFileType **/ 
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
/** Advise the Reader of which WorkSheets we want to load **/ 
$objReader->setLoadSheetsOnly($sheetnames); 
/**  Load $inputFileName to a PHPExcel Object  **/
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
```

If you only need to access part of a worksheet, then you can define a Read Filter to identify just which cells you actually want to load:

```
$inputFileType = 'Excel5'; 
$inputFileName = './sampleData/example1.xls';
$sheetname = 'Data Sheet #3'; 

/**  Define a Read Filter class implementing PHPExcel_Reader_IReadFilter  */ 
class MyReadFilter implements PHPExcel_Reader_IReadFilter {
    public function readCell($column, $row, $worksheetName = '') {
        //  Read rows 1 to 7 and columns A to E only 
        if ($row >= 1 && $row <= 7) {
           if (in_array($column,range('A','E'))) { 
              return true;
           }
        } 
        return false;
    }
}

/**  Create an Instance of our Read Filter  **/ 
$filterSubset = new MyReadFilter(); 
/** Create a new Reader of the type defined in $inputFileType **/ 
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
/**  Advise the Reader of which WorkSheets we want to load 
     It's more efficient to limit sheet loading in this manner rather than coding it into a Read Filter  **/ 
$objReader->setLoadSheetsOnly($sheetname); 
echo 'Loading Sheet using filter';
/**  Tell the Reader that we want to use the Read Filter that we've Instantiated  **/ 
$objReader->setReadFilter($filterSubset); 
/**  Load only the rows and columns that match our filter from $inputFileName to a PHPExcel Object  **/
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
```

If you don't need to load formatting information, but only the worksheet data, then the setReadDataOnly() method will tell the reader only to load cell values, ignoring any cell formatting:

```
$inputFileType = 'Excel5';
$inputFileName = './sampleData/example1.xls';
/** Create a new Reader of the type defined in $inputFileType **/ 
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
/** Advise the Reader that we only want to load cell data, not formatting **/ 
$objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
/**  Load $inputFileName to a PHPExcel Object  **/
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
```

although note that reading only the raw data like this won't allow you to differentiate between date values and floats

---

If you want to work with large Excel files, don't build a large PHP array in memory by making that `toArray()` call, because that's a big overhead in memory usage, and there's also a big cost in performance with the constant need to allocate more and more memory as the array is built..... if you're going to process a row at a time, use the iterators built into PHPExcel, or just use a loop to access each individual row in turn.